# javascript drop-down filling

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am populating my dropdown through javascript using ASP.NET, and for that I have taken the help of one of the answers on this site. I used the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("Hi");
        var select = document.getElementById('<%=ddlItems%>');
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = "1";
        option.innerHTML = "Option1";
        select.appendChild(option);

    });
</script>
```

It's not working. For checking whether the program flow is entering function, I have put an alert box. It's showing me the proper alert, which means its entering the function but below that code is not working. What may be the problem?

Comment: check the console for any errors

Comment: I made a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/BdhVv/  It seems to work fine for me, what does <%=ddItems%> turn into once the page is served? Make sure it's the same as the id of the element.

Comment: @DON console is blank.nothing showing me on console

Comment: Respected User, are you sure `<%=ddlItems%>` is the id of an element on the page?  Seems like a strange id for some reason.  Please post your html.

Comment: are you getting `select` as an `object`?

Comment: @PaulHoenecke yeah. i am sure ddlItems is the id of control

Comment: If the id is ddItems, try `document.getElementById('ddlItems');`

Comment: @PaulHoenecke It worked now. Thanks . why not it worked when it was <%=ddlItems%> . And in one of the stackoverflow answers also i have seen this.

Comment: @ZohoGorganzola : thank you for jsfiddle.net/BdhVv

Comment: Not an expert with asp.net, but I think <%=ddlItems%> is a server-side rendering thing maybe...  From client side javascript, you just use the id.  Like if the html is `<select id='ddItems'></select>` then you look for that id from js.

Comment: @PaulHoenecke Hoenecke :It was intended to deal with server side controls using javascript. It should have been <%=ddlItems.ClientID%> as Wiz Kid shown in his answer.

Comment: Hmm, ok glad you got it worked out!

Comment: here is a good for implementing domready on javascript. https://github.com/dsrdakota/onDomReady

Comment: thanx. I think document.onload  is the function for loading javascript function on page load @naveen

Comment: @freelancer: not it is not. :) see the jquery implementation for DOMReady.. http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.bindReady

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ddlItems.ClientID

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("Hi");
        var select = document.getElementById('<%=ddlItems.ClientID%>');
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = "1";
        option.innerHTML = "Option1";
        select.appendChild(option);

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi would you be able to tell me how i populate an asp:dropdownlist with data from a sql table instead of hard coding the data? i have searched every where and unable to find a solution. Thnkas

Answer (score 3):

Try this way. set your id mode to static for `dropdownlist`

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:DropDownList>
```

and change your script to

```
var select = document.getElementById('ddl');
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can add option as follows:

```
$('#ddlItems').append($('<option></option>').val("1").html("option1"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use clientID after the dropdownlist id..

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     alert("Hi");
    var select = document.getElementById('<%=ddlItems.ClientID%>');
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "1";
    option.innerHTML = "Option1";
    select.appendChild(option);

 });
 </script>
```